# Get url address from focused browser tab

Tags: java, c++, browser

I have console application, based on JNA, and can get whish browser is opened.

```
 char[] buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
    PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), pointer);
    Pointer process = OpenProcess(Kernel32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
   // GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
   // Pointer process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
    GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
    System.out.println("Active window process: " +Native.toString(buffer));
```

Something like this.
But, can some body provide me a link how can I read opened url in browser. As I know, there are different methods for different browsers. 
If it is possible to make on C+, please provide some information.

Comment: `FindWindowW` to get the Address-Bar's handle. `GetWindowTextW` to get the url.

Comment: Ok. but how can I use FindWindow? What kind of _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpClassName, _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpWindowName parameters I need to use?